# Creating a New Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I just created a new calendar, however, it does not appear in the list on the left. Nor have I been able to add any information onto this new calendar. Help!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

At the left side, you should see the calendars and the links as 'My Calendars' and 'Other Calendars'. There is a little arrow at the right of the calendar when you hover on the link of the calendar. Click on the arrow and you will be able to create new event by clicking the create new event link in the hover menu.

[image]